# How can I draw a progressing ring with a gradient in Android?

Tags: android, automatic-ref-counting, gradient, shapedrawable

I have a ShapeDrawable Object in my class in the form of an arc.

```
ShapeDrawable progressArc = new ShapeDrawable(new ArcShape(120, 12));
```

Now I would like to use a radial gradient effect on the color and also display just a ring instead of a filled arc. Does the Android SDK provide such a feature?

Currently using the below code, I get a gradient on the circle.

```
progressArc.setIntrinsicHeight(500);
progressArc.setIntrinsicWidth(500);

Shader shader1 = new LinearGradient(5, -5, 35, 0, new int[] { 0xFF33B5E5,0xFFFFFFFF }, null, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
progressArc.getPaint().setShader(shader1);
progressArc.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(1);
progressArc.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
progressArc.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`SweepGradient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SweepGradient.html) to get a radial gradient:

```
Shader s = new SweepGradient(0, 0, new int[] { 0xFF33B5E5,0xFFFFFFFF }, null);
//or if you only use two colors:
Shader s = new SweepGradient(0, 0, 0xFF33B5E5, 0xFFFFFFFF);
```

To avoid filling, just use the `Paint.Style.STROKE` style, with appropriate `strokeWidth`.